# Visual Studio 2010 UML Tools. How do they integrate with the code? For small/mid size products is there any value in using them?

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, uml

I just got a book that goes over all the VS2010 tools. Most I have never used like load testing/web testing, UML Tools, Layer Diagrams....

Has anyone had any real world experience with using these VS2010 tools like the UML diagramming? I am wondering if it is something that would really be useful starting a new project or is it just busy work that no one ever uses once they are made?

How are the UML diagrams integrated with the rest of development in VS2010 ?

The last project we just made some really basic Visio diagrams but maybe this is better. Alot of VS2010 Ultimate tools are over kill (layer diagram) for small/mid level projects it seems.

UML seems to be one of those things I hear about past 10 years but never seem to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well UML is important in the sense if you do the diagrams before the start of the project you would pretty much be able to steer your project before coding. It also helps the developers in communicating with each other.

VS 2010 has a lot of new features. One feature I am currently using is to generate sequence diagrams from the code(yes I had to submit a design document) and VS2010 architect edition has it. I am able to generate sequence diagrams of it. I am not sure if other tools are out there which can do the same. 
VS2010 can also generate code from the class diagram and vice versa.

Comment: Yes I have created a sequence diagram from code and Im aware of generating code from class diagram.. What did your design document consist of? UML diagrams from VS2010 ? 

I guess I am just wondering why there is such little information about the UML tools. Is it one of those soon to be forgotten tools of VS2010 ?

Comment: Yep it consisted of UML diagrams from VS2010.

Comment: Did your code refer to those UML documents in any way? 

Or are the UML documents completely isolated from the actualy code? 

I was hoping since the UML designer its built into VS2010 .. there would be be integration with other parts of vs2010

Comment: No they were independent. The documents were isolated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the product documentation here: [Modeling the Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57b85fsc.aspx)? It contains guidance about how to use the UML tools with code at any point in your development cycle. Have you also looked at the dependency graphs?

Comment: Yes. I have seen that. I am interested in hearing real world scenerios where these tools were used and how much it helped. Some tools are nice but in reality do not do much except create pretty pictures

Comment: You can link model elements to your work items to help you track development and test work. You might also want to read what the team will ship in the upcoming feature pack to extend the UML tools:

http://blogs.msdn.com/camerons/archive/2010/03/19/announcing-the-first-feature-pack-for-vs2010-visualization-and-modeling-tools.aspx